# Did hortan sandbox can use as a single node Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, sandbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I like to study about Hadoop multinode setup and installation, by referring the above tutorial I understand that single node cluster environment can be used as node for the multinode cluster

http://bigdatahandler.com/hadoop-hdfs/hadoop-multi-node-cluster-setup/

Currently I am learning Hadoop using Horton sandbox, can we use a sandbox system as a single node environment?

If not what is the difference between sandbox and traditional Hadoop cluster installation

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox images (from Hortonworks and Cloudera) provide the user with a pre-configured development environment with all the usual tools already available and installed (pig, hive etc.). Since the image is a single "system" it is set-up such that the hadoop cluster is single-node: i.e. everything - HDFS, Hadoop map-reduce etc. - is local to that image. That is a massive benefit, as anyone who has set up a hadoop cluster will tell you! It allows you to get up-and-running with very little operational overhead.

What these sandboxes do not provide, however, is realistic cluster behaviour as you have only one node. But there other possibilities - tools such as Vagrant and Docker - that would allow you to do this (I have not tried it myself).

The big data handler link you shared seems to be about combining several of these standalone, inherently single-node "clusters" so that you have something more realistic. But I would guess setting this up so that YARN, Zookeeper and other services are not duplicated comes with a not insignificant challenge.